# How to perform an operation with two columns in the same dataframe in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm trying to apply the operation `'x-y/y'`, being `x` the column `'Faturamento'` and `y` column `'Custo'` from the dataframe called `'df'`, and store the results in a new column called `'Roi'`.

My attempt to use the apply function:

```
df['Roi'] = df.apply(lambda x, y: x['Faturamento']-y['Custo']/y['Custo'], axis=1)
```

Is returning:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

How can I do this?

Comment: Try changing that line to: `df['Roi'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Faturamento']-x['Custo'])/x['Custo'], axis=1)
`

Comment: @Anwarvic that works, thanks ;)

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Use built-in Pandas function whenever possible.  This case, you don't need to rely on `.apply()` and lambda function, which is used mostly for situation without built-in function.   Just use column-wise operation by Pandas would be the best for this use case.

Comment: @SeaBean thanks, good tip!

Comment: I'm going to give you some benchmarking figures and you will know the difference.

Comment: See the huge difference of **833x times faster for Pandas built-in column-wise operation** vs `.apply` + `lambda` function for dataset of 40000 rows.   Even for small dataset of 4 rows, Pandas built-in is still faster.

Comment: Definitely you should use the Pandas built-in arithmetic operation function instead of using `.apply()` + `lambda`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the column operation with syntax like simple arithmetic.  Pandas will automatically align the index for you, so that you are operating row by row for each operation.

```
df['Roi'] = (df['Faturamento'] - df['Custo']) / df['Custo']
```

or

```
df['Roi'] = df['Faturamento'] / df['Custo'] - 1
```

This way, you can enjoy the fast vectorized processing of Pandas which has been optimized to run fast.  If you use `.apply()` with lambda function on `axis=1`, it's just a slow Python loop in underlying processing, and will be slow.

#### Performance Benchmark

**Test 1. Small `df` with 4 rows**

```
   Faturamento  Custo
0           50     20
1           10      5
2            5     15
3          100    400
```

```
%%timeit
df['Roi'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Faturamento']-x['Custo'])/x['Custo'], axis=1)

721 µs ± 3.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df['Roi'] = df['Faturamento'] / df['Custo'] - 1

490 µs ± 4.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Summary:  `.apply` + lambda takes **`721 µs`**  while Pandas built-in takes **`490 µs`**:  **1.47 times faster for small dataset of .**

**Test 2. Large `df` with 40000 rows**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit
df2['Roi'] = df2.apply(lambda x: (x['Faturamento']-x['Custo'])/x['Custo'], axis=1)

639 ms ± 3.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
df2['Roi'] = df2['Faturamento'] / df2['Custo'] - 1

767 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Summary:  `.apply` + lambda takes **`639 ms (= 639,000 µs)`** while Pandas built-in takes **`767 µs`**:  **833x times faster for large dataset of .**

Comment: yass!!! thank you, that works

Comment: @CarolVieira  I think you should use a vectorized and yet simpler version like this solution, rather than still using `.apply` and lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
df['Roi'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Faturamento']-x['Custo'])/x['Custo'], axis=1)
```

`x` refers to the dataframe